# Jest Client Size Parameter Ignored

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using the Jest Client to query Elasticsearch from my Java program.  Everything works correctly except that when I add the "size" parameter it is ignored. Building and execution of the Search is like so:

```
Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .addIndex(index)
    .addType(type)
    .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, 1)
    .build();
jestClient.execute(search);
```

This query always returns 10 results, instead of the 1 result expected.  In case it is relevant, there are only 5 shards, so it is not returning a result per shard.

Is there any particular reason this parameter is ignored?  When running the same query with the same parameters on the command line with 'curl -XGET' or when simply putting it in the browser the query runs correctly and the size parameter *is* taken in to account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had a misunderstanding of how the size parameter was working.  I believe Jest *was* handling it correctly when sizing the **query** results, but what I was actually interested in were the **aggregation** results.

Adding a "size" parameter to my aggregation worked, as can be seen in the [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) docs (copied below).

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "products" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "product",
                "size" : 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```